# Python Zip an existing directory in to a temporary directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to compress an existing directory (containing sub folders) in to a temporary directory, so I can upload to cloud storage. The zip file should not remain locally.

I see `shutil.make_archive` but I can't see how to use this with a temporary directory.

Is it supposed to be used like this:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as zippedDir:
    shutil.make_archive("/dir_to_zip/", "zip", zippedDir)
```

Comment: Perhaps look into `zipfile`, [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects).  Very simple and straightforward to use.  Can also be used to extract the zip easily.

Comment: you will have to move it manually to  temporary filder. OR maybe you should first move to temporary folder using `os.chdir(zippedDir)` and then compress - but it may need different `/dir_to_zip/`

Comment: If you choose to use `zipfile`, the temp folder can be created automatically, and the zip stored there.  By coincidence, I wrote just that thing yesterday using the docs linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving files to a temp directory automatically can be done very easily with the built-in `zipfile` library.  The [docs can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects).

Illustrated below is an example of:

- Creating a temp directory.
- Archiving all files like `test*` from the defined root path.
- Viewing the files which have been archived.
- Then, remove the temp directory, if you wish.

#### Example:

```
import os
import zipfile
from glob import glob

# Define root directory containing files to be zipped.
d_root = os.path.expanduser('~/temp/ziptest')
# Define a temp directory, off of the root (or anywhere you like).
d_temp = os.path.join(d_root, os.urandom(8).hex())

# Create the temp directory.
if not os.path.exists(d_temp):
    os.makedirs(d_temp)

# Archive all files like test* from the root directory to archive.zip.
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(d_temp, 'archive.zip'), 'w') as zf:
    for f in glob(os.path.join(d_root, 'test*')):
        # Use arcname to remove the full path to the file, use base filename only.
        zf.write(f, arcname=os.path.basename(f))
```

---

#### Outputs:

Files in the root directory:

```
# Show files in root directory.
os.listdir(d_root)

['testfile_8', 'testfile_5', 'testfile_6', 'testfile_7',
 'testfile_1', 'testfile_3', 'testfile_2', 'testfile_4',
 '057d3cccb248ef3c', 'testfile_10', 'testfile_9']
```

Files in the temp directory:

```
# Show files in temp directory.
os.listdir(d_temp)

['archive.zip']
```

Display the archived files:

```
# Show archived files.
zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(d_temp, 'archive.zip')).filelist

[<ZipInfo filename='testfile_8' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_5' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_6' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_7' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_1' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_3' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_2' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_4' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_10' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>,
 <ZipInfo filename='testfile_9' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=0>]
```